# How can I make the button more visible?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, button

I got an ion-button (button using the ionic framework) that's just too low. This is an ionic/angular project. I feel like I've tried everything to pull it up, but my attempts have resulted in failures (pulling the button up but the button aligns left; pushing button down; pulling button up but the button budges a little right of center... etc). I've tried playing with margin, spacing, padding; I've tried absolute positioning; I've even tried flexbox and ion-grid.

All I want to do is pull up the button, almost like a footer, and keep it centered.

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML code

```
<div class="bottomBar">
  <ion-button> <!-- <fill="block" style="position: absolute; bottom:50px;"> -->
    Order Skirt
  </ion-button>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.bottomBar {
  z-index: 2;
  //padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  //margin-left: 50vw;
  //margin-right: 50%;
  //width: 100% - 30px;
}
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a button fixed to the bottom of the viewport, see this:

```css
/* draw outline around div (for demonstration only) */
div {
  outline: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}

/* bar fixed to bottom */
.bottomBar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1024;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/* center contents of div */
.center-contents {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomBar center-contents">
  <button> 
    Order Skirt
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: And then I just change bottom:0 to bottom:15px and we're in business.

Comment: @not_overrated It's a bit cleaner to add `padding-bottom: 15px` to the div, instead. See edit above.

Comment: I confirm the comment made by @terrymorse